# Context: Remove Blank Line Below Sub-Section

Tags: context

I'm learning how to use Context, and I'm having trouble creating a sub-section heading without a blank line underneath it. I'm using a baseline grid and want to continue to do so.

Is there a way to eliminate the blank line between "Sub-Section 1" and its paragraph? I accomplished the look I want in "Sub-Section 2", but it doesn't use a section heading and cannot be referenced.

[image]

```
% macros=mkvi
\usemodule[ipsum]

\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupbodyfont[10pt]

\definefont [Heading] [Serif at 20pt]
\definefont [ParagraphHeading] [SerifItalic at 13pt]

\setuphead [section] [
  style=\Heading,
  number=no,
  align=middle,
  before=,
  after=
]

\setuphead [subsection] [
  style=\ParagraphHeading,
  number=no,
  align=flushleft,
  before=,
  after=
]

\setupinterlinespace[line=1.5em]
\setuplayout [grid=yes]
\showgrid

\starttext
  \section{Section}
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]

  \subsection{Sub-Section 1}
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]

  \blank[1.5em]
  {\it \switchtobodyfont[13pt]{Sub-Section 2}}\\
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid snapping can get quite tricky.

The issue here is that you're using a larger font size in the headings, so the "depth" of the headings would overlap with the "height" of the following line. You can use `grid=high` to force the depths to round down instead of rounding up:

```tex
% macros=mkvi
\usemodule[ipsum]

\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupbodyfont[10pt]

% Added: *default
\definefont [Heading] [Serif*default at 20pt]
\definefont [ParagraphHeading] [SerifItalic*default at 13pt]

\setuphead [section] [
  style=\Heading,
  number=no,
  align=middle,
  before=,
  after=,
  grid=high,
]

\setuphead [subsection] [
  style=\ParagraphHeading,
  number=no,
  align=flushleft,
  before=,
  after=,
  grid=high,
]

\setupinterlinespace[line=1.5em]
\setuplayout [grid=yes]
\showgrid

\showmakeup[line] % Visualize the line heights/depths

\starttext
  \section{Section}
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]

  \subsection{Sub-Section 1}
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]

  \blank[1.5em]
  {\it \switchtobodyfont[13pt]{Sub-Section 2}}\\
  \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=2]
\stoptext
```

The ["It's in the Details"](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual has some more information about grid snapping, although it's a pretty technical read.

Also, you should almost always add `*default` when using `\define(d)font` to make sure that you get all of the default font features.